# Object.create() not creating, creates an empty object

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I have done similar work in other projects, but for whatever reason, this is not working.  The object created is {} instead of what I would expect, see code below...

javascript

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

const Referral = {
    ReferrorInformation : {
        ReferralOwner : "",
        CreatedDate : new Date().toISOString(),
        Email : "",
        Phone : "",
        Fax : "",
        School : ""
    }
}

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    referralToUpdate = Object.create(Referral);
    contactEmail = 'blah@test.com';
    userId = '1111222';
    contactFax = '555-1212';
    contactPhone = '555-1313';
    contact = { AccountId: 234 };
    output;

    renderedCallback() {
        this.output = JSON.stringify(this.referralToUpdate, null, 4);
    }

    handleClick = (event) => {
        this.referralToUpdate.updatedDate = new Date().toISOString();
        this.referralToUpdate.ReferrorInformation.Email = this.contactEmail;
        this.referralToUpdate.ReferrorInformation.ReferralOwner = this.userId;
        this.referralToUpdate.ReferrorInformation.Fax = this.contactFax;
        this.referralToUpdate.ReferrorInformation.Phone = this.contactPhone;
        this.referralToUpdate.ReferrorInformation.School = this.contact.AccountId;
        this.output = {...this.output};
    }
}
```

template

```
<template>
    {output}
    <p><button type="submit" onclick={handleClick} title="Refresh">Refresh</button></p>
</template>
```

What I would expect is the object properties are set, what I get is only the date that I set.  I suspect it is a shallow clone issue, but not sure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a shallow clone issue. You can test this in your browser console (create a New Tab, and go to the browser's Developer Console):

```
const a = { b: { c: 'hello world' } };
const b = Object.create(a);
console.log(b); // {}
```

You need to use a deep-clone technique in order to recreate your object.

Comment: Yep that was it, tried a deep copy first, but didn't realize there was an error in my code and thought it was due to this issue so I backed out those changes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer here is actually incorrect. It is not a shallow clone issue. The reason b is showing as an empty object is because of prototypal inheritance. if you were to `console.log(b.__proto__)`, you'd see that those properties are on the prototype and both b.b as well as b.b.c are accessible.